Problem with equation of thrust in a system of variable mass
The equation for force on a system of variable mass (e.g. a rocket thrust equation) is
$$F=-u\frac{\mathrm{d}m}{\mathrm{d}t}$$
where $u$ is the velocity of the escaping gases with respect to the rocket. It is said that
$$F_{\mathrm{ext}}+F_{\mathrm{thrust}}=m\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}t}$$
We know that the velocity $v$ of the rocket isn't constant, and neither is its mass. Then whose mass is $m$ referring to?
Also, $u$ is constant. It's said that
$$-v_{\mathrm{gas}}-v=u$$
Now $v$ isn't constant but $v_{\mathrm{gas}}$ sure is. But, a sum of a constant and a variable should be variable... So how does this work? Please help.

In that equation (with the force-external and force-thrust) $m$ refers to the instantaneous mass of the rocket at any given point in time. You're asking about how one calculates the acceleration of a rocket whose mass changes, right? If so, I'd recommend a look at the Tsiolkovsky rocket equation.

$u$ is magnitude of velocity of the escaping gases wrt the rocket, thus always a nonnegative number. Thus the last equation is wrong. The correct relation is $v_{gas} = v - u$, thus on the rocket start, it is negative, but later, as the rocket gets faster than $u$, it becomes positive.


... whose mass is m referring to?

$m$ is the initial mass of the rocket-fuel system. It is thus a constant. As the rocket propels, its mass is reduced to $m - dm$, where $dm$ is the mass of the fuel ejected. Hence, the force exerted by the fuel ejection against the rocket is as such:
$$
F_{fuel} = -u \frac{dm}{dt}
$$
In this case, $u$ is the rate at which the fuel is ejected relative to the rocket. The fuel ejection rate relative to earth ($u_{earth}$) is given as follows:
$$
u_{earth} = v - u
$$
Note that in most textbooks, $u$ is assumed constant for simplification. In reality, $u$ changes as the rocket enters a different layer of the atmosphere with different characteristics. Or, say, you need to change the rocket's thrusting rate in order to change its course.
Given $v$ the initial velocity of the rocket (it could be zero, if the rocket starts from rest) and the fuel mass that was initially within the rocket, the rocket gains $dv$ as it ejects $dm$ of fuel. Thus the total velocity of the rocket now becomes $v + dv$. We can use momentum conservation to predict the rocket-fuel dynamics. Again, this is a simplification since air resistance, which we neglect, steals away a part of the rocket's upward momentum. The only external force which we will be considering now is gravity. (Note that the momentum is considered relative to earth. Thus, we will use $u_{earth}$ in the fuel's momentum instead of just $u$.)
$$
\begin{align*}
p_{before} &= p_{after} - p_{ext} \\
mv &= p_{rocket} + p_{fuel} - p_{grav} \\
mv &= (m - dm)(v + dv) + (u_{earth})(dm) - p_{grav} \\
mv &= m v + m dv - v dm - dm dv + (v - u) dm - p_{grav} \\
\end{align*}
$$
We can ignore the $dm dv$ term because multiplication of infinitesimal values and infinitesimal value approximates zero. Meanwhile, the value of $p_{grav}$ is $m g dt$. Thus:
$$
\begin{align*}
0 &= m dv - v dm + (v - u) dm - m g dt \\
0 &= m dv - v dm + v dm - u dm - m g dt \\
0 &= m dv - u dm - m g dt \\
m g dt + u dm &= m dv \\
\end{align*}
$$
Derive all of the terms with respect to time in order to obtain force:
$$
\begin{align*}
m g + u \frac{dm}{dt} &= m \frac{dv}{dt} \\
F_{grav} - F_{fuel} &= m \frac{dv}{dt} \\
\end{align*}
$$
In your case, $F_{thrust} = - F_{fuel}$, because the rocket's thrust direction is opposite of the fuel's ejection (Newton's third law). $F_{grav}$ is $F_{ext}$ in your case, but really $F_{ext}$ must also account for air resistance in reality, not just gravity.

Now $v$ isn't constant but $v_{gas}$ sure is. But, a sum of a constant and a variable should be variable... So how does this work?

As I said earlier, $v$ is the rocket's initial velocity. It is considered at one time reference $t$, and could be whatever initial condition you are considering. But since $v$ is our initial condition, it needs not to change. What is variable is the velocity change of the rocket as it moves, $dv$, which is considered at two time references, $t$ (when the velocity is $v$) and $t + dt$ (when the velocity is $v + dv$).
So, no, $v$ is not not a constant.
(Source: University Physics Part I 6th ed. 1982 by Francis W. Sears, Mark W. Zemansky, and Hugh D. Young; Addison-Wesley Publishing Co. pp. 157)


In reality, $u$ changes as the rocket enters a different layer of the atmosphere with different characteristics. -- Do you mean direction of exhaust changes (which it has, to rotate the rocket), or magnitude of exhaust velocity wrt to the rocket nozzle changes too?


I think the magnitude of the thurst changes, too. As David Hammen pointed out here, rocket exhaust is typically 15% to 20% faster in vacuum than at sea level. Thus, the magnitude of exhaust velocity in the thermosphere (where gas density is lower, almost vacuum-like) should be faster than when the rocket is in the troposphere.

Decrease of atmospheric pressure means the nozzle becomes under-extended; the exhaust gas goes also in transverse directions, and net thrust should decrease. Maybe @DavidHammen meant that in vacuum, different, vacuum-optimized nozzle is used, and for that different nozzle, the exhaust speed is higher?
